# Does it some prime factors rule/pattern/behavior has name?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm not a mathematician, so sorry for the strange question.

First, I discovered (for me) that a prime number written several times in a row always contains itself as one of its prime factors.
E.g. :
37**37** = **37** × 101

131313**13** = **13** × 73 × 101 × 137

Indeed it part of more general rule/pattern: *if we decompose any number into prime factors, then append (not add, append!) one of them to the beginning or end of the original number (as many times as you like) we get a number that has in its multiples this factor again.*

Let take for example 12345 or 98761:

12345 = 3 × 5 × **823**

Append to begin or end 3 or 5 or 823 and new number will has it as its prime factor also:

12345**823** = 7 × **823** × 2143 or

**823**12345 = 5 × 83 × 241 × **823**

For 98761 = 13 × 71 × 107 we append 71 (doesn’t matter 13, 71 or 107 it will be, but it will not work of course with another primes like 11 or 29 here):

98761**71** = 3 × **71** × 199 × 233

It’s rule works for all numbers, even on your phone number. Check it)
It’s understandable enough why it happened. But maybe that rule/pattern has some name?

Comment: $~[ ~p \times (\text{some factor-1}) ~] + [ ~p \times (\text{some factor-2}) ~] = \text{a multiple of} ~p.$  Here, some-factor-1 has form *something like* $~10^k \times 1010101,~$ and some-factor-2 has form $~\dfrac{n}{p},~$ where $~p~$ is a factor of $~n.$

Comment: If $n$ has $k$ digits, then making a concatenation of $m$ times $n$ will result in a number that has the factorization $n\cdot \underbrace{1\underbrace{0\ldots0}_{k-1\, times}  }_{m \, times}\ldots1$, where there are $k-1$ zeros between the ones, and there are $m$ ones.

Comment: And similarly if $a$ divides $b$ and $a$ divides $c$, then $a$ divides the concatenation of $b$ and $c$ (which is $10^d b + c$ where $d$ is the number of digits of $c$).  Whether $a$ is prime or not is irrelevant.

Comment: I quote Robert's answer.
Anyway, if you wish to go further on this path, let me share this old paper of mine about the patterns of prime factors described by permutations of the string $1\_2\_3\_\ldots\_n$ (for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$).

Comment: Marco Ripà, sure. It would be great if you share your article.

Comment: @DoktorNikita Here it is: https://nntdm.net/volume-18-2012/number-1/29-48/